# How to Customize the Query Behind the Features Board

Tags: azure-devops

I have a scrum project in Azure DevOps. I have already created many features, and some of them are in the Done state. My problem is, not all of the features are visible on the Features board. I can't find some of them which were created months ago and are in the Done state. How can I change the query which provides the content for this board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. This is because:

> Your backlog shows work that you plan to do or have started to work
>   on. As soon as the state of a work item is set to Done or Completed,
>   the work item no longer shows up on your backlog.

The above is quoted from Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/create-your-backlog?view=azure-devops#convert-ideas-into-backlog-items-or-stories) and there is a recent-ish (2017) request closed as 'not a bug' [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/106221/backlog-items-in-done-state-not-showing-on-backlog.html)

You can however [create your own queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops).